Python datetime and timezone mismatch in difference
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz
today = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
today_again = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print(today - today_again, today.tzinfo)

Why is the difference between today and today_again datetime object is 1 day and not zero?
Tried it without timezone info and found out to be working fine

You're misreading the output. The difference is -1 day, 23:59:59.979191 Asia/Kolkata when I ran it, which is true - it's -1 day but then the difference is made up almost entirely by the second portion adding back 23 hours, 59 minutes etc. etc. The program can't run instantaneously, so the difference comes from the time it takes to make the function calls

besides, replace is not to be used with pytz timezone objects, see Weird timezone issue with pytz. And you should be using zoneinfo in the first place for tz handling. But the actual issue here is already clarified by @roganjosh.

You're misunderstanding the output. Functions take time to call, and the difference you're seeing is the fact that time has passed between the function calls. The way it's represented is not exactly ideal, but it subtracts 1 day and then adds back the discrepancy in hours, minutes and seconds.
When I ran the code, I got 23:59:59.979191, which means it took 0.02... seconds between the function calls.
If you want the actual day difference, use:
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz
today = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
today_again = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print((today_again - today).days)


The reason you're seeing a difference of 1 day between today and today_again when using timezone information is because you're capturing the current time twice. Since there can be a tiny gap of milliseconds between the two captures, even though it might seem like the same moment, the computer sees them as slightly different times. This tiny difference causes Python to round up and show a difference of 1 day.
However, when you capture the time without timezone information, both today and today_again represent the exact same moment, so the difference between them is 0.
To avoid this, you can capture the time once and reuse it for both today and today_again. This ensures they represent the same day without any time difference, giving you the result you expect.

this is probably due you are compaing two datetime objects directly and today object is executed/made earlier then today_again
so according to datetime documentation, how two datetime object work in substraction as
Subtraction of a datetime from a datetime is defined only if both operands are naive, or if both are aware. If one is aware and the other is naive, TypeError is raised.

If both are naive, or both are aware and have the same tzinfo attribute, the tzinfo attributes are ignored, and the result is a timedelta object t such that datetime2 + t == datetime1. No time zone adjustments are done in this case.

If both are aware and have different tzinfo attributes, a-b acts as if a and b were first converted to naive UTC datetimes. The result is (a.replace(tzinfo=None) - a.utcoffset()) - (b.replace(tzinfo=None) - b.utcoffset()) except that the implementation never overflows

>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> import pytz
>>> today = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
>>> today_again = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
>>>
>>> z = (today.replace(tzinfo=None) - today.utcoffset()) - (today_again.replace(tzinfo=None) - today_again.utcoffset())
>>> z
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86399, microseconds=400808)
>>> z.days
-1


I vote that we just go back to hourglasses. I'm so fed up with datetimes

lol, it would be great :D , datetime sometimes become too much just for recording time
